# Add new column values based on other 2 column values in Pandas, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the below code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':
    ['apple','banana','lemon','apple','apple'],
    'price':
    [2,3,7,21,11],
    'stock':
    ['Yes','No','No','No','Yes']
})
```

The dataframe looks like this

```
    name    price   stock
0   apple   2        Yes
1   banana  3        No
2   lemon   7        No
3   apple   21       No
4   apple   11      Yes
```

I need to add new column, 'STATUS' to the same df, based on the values in two other columns.
If name is apple and if stock is Yes, then status should be "GOLD"
If name is apple and if stock is No, then status should be "Bronze"
If name is banana or lemon and if stock is No, then status should be "Silver"

How do I go about this?

I can add a new column based on one column but how is it possible with 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
df['STATUS'] = None
df.loc[(df['name'] == 'apple') & (df['stock'] == 'Yes'), 'STATUS'] = 'GOLD'
df.loc[(df['name'] == 'apple') & (df['stock'] == 'No'), 'STATUS'] = 'Bronze'
df.loc[(df['name'].isin(('banana', 'lemon'))) & (df['stock'] == 'No'), 'STATUS'] = 'Silver'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try via `np.select()`:

```
import numpy as np

conditions=[
    (df['name']=='apple') & (df['stock']=='Yes'),
    (df['name']=='apple') & (df['stock']=='No'),
    (df['name'].isin(['banana','lemon'])) & (df['stock']=='No')
]
labels=['Gold','Bronze','Silver']
```

Finally:

```
df['STATUS']=np.select(conditions,labels,default=np.nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the code below

```
df["status"] = None
df.loc[(df["name"] == "apple") & (df["stock"] == "Yes"), "status"] = "Gold"
df
name    price   stock   status
0   apple   2   Yes     Gold
1   banana  3   No  None
2   lemon   7   No  None
3   apple   21  No  None
4   apple   11  Yes     Gold
```